# How to get a file from URL when there is no local file with `try_files` in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Suppose you have a request for the following json file.

```
https://example.com/static/xxx/fileName.json
```

I would like to know how to get a file from a URL when there is no local file. It looks like I can use `@external` to move the request to another location, but how do I pass the file name along?

```
server_name example.com;

# location-A
# Ignore the $0. The $1 is the file name.
location ~ ^\/static\/[0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+\/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+.json) {
    alias /abc/nginx/html/;
    try_files $1 @external;
}

# location-B
# I want to retrieve a file from an external URL, how do I pass $1?
location @external{
    # proxy_pass https://example123456789.com/path/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [rewrite](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) to get the part of URL you need.

```
location @external {
  rewrite ^\/static\/[0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+\/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+.json)$ $1 break;
  proxy_pass https://example123456789.com/path;
}
```